A 1980's or 1990's Movie about two sister's or possibly (Friends) that go to a town
I need immediate help finding this old horror classic. I believe it is from the mid 1990's and from what I can remember from my childhood. 
It begins with two sisters or possibly; (friends), that revisit either their hometown or a relative that lives there. Not knowing what to expect. They realize the town is deserted.
When they go on with their personal investigation, they bump into a group of gentlemen that tag along for the ride. Things start to get weird when an insect like creature kills a guy with glasses; "being part of the group". They continue along with even more unusual experiences when the CDC I believe arrives and quarantine an area where they see an ordinary dog. I believe a golden retriever. 
One CDC individual calls out to the dog and no response. He engages even closer and still no movement, nor a response.
Finally when he she's that all has failed and the dog simply will not interact with him. 
The dog lashes out with a black elongated substance that infects and kills the CDC worker!!!
So from what I can mainly remember is that this creature that has killed everyone in town. Not really infected. No one is around. As I may have made it sound like, some kind of alien infection going around.
Anyways, this creature mainly shapeshifts into a boy whom I swear is the little boy actor Haley Osmentn that this creature reveals itself before manifesting as it's true and natural form.
That's it. All that I can remember.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

It's got to be Phantoms. This was based on a Dean Koontz book by the same name. It has two sisters visit their small town and they find it empty. 
They run into some cops (one is Ben Afflect) and go about investigating the town. Strange things happen - there's creatures, giant moths, all are manifestations of an entity that thinks it's the devil. 
At one point the CDC is called in as is "Timothy Flyte", who wrote about the creature in books about mass disappearances. The creature either infects or takes over a bunch of animals. At one point I believe they are running out of a forest. 
The weird insect creature is a huge moth. 
